# BusinessObjects .NET SDK - Error when executing SDK code

Tags: business-objects-sdk

I'm trying to create a .NET 3.5 Console Application that uses the Business Objects XI3.1 .NET SDK. I've pulled in all libraries needed to compile the application.

I'm compiling in Visual Studio 2012, on Windows 2008 64-bit.

When I call into get a new 'SessionMgr' an error occurs.

```
Try
    sm = New SessionMgr
Catch ex As Exception
    'Error Shown below
End Try
```

Error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with {CLSD 3EBB7859-E4E3-4D77-B673-C6E5AD529CC1} failed due to the following error:80040154
```

Answer (score 0):

The BusinessObjects SDK code is compiled against x86, and if you try to run this code on an 64-bit machine, there will be an error unless you compile the program only to run in x86 mode.

To compile in x86, you need to go into your project settings, and change the Target CPU to be x86.

[image: Change the Target CPU setting]